# Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking Field - Physical Significance.

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

One way to define spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) is as follows (Morandi, Ercolessi and Napoli, 2001; my wording):

> We can define SSB as occurring when:
>   $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \langle\mathcal{O}\rangle_{N,b}\ne 0\tag{1}$$
>   where $\mathcal{O}$ is some quantity which is **not** invariant under the symmetry.

I understand mathematically why this order of limits must be taken (rather then having the $h$ limit first). But why is this the case physically and why does the condition (1) correspond to SSB?

Comment: A good reference for this is: Altland and Simions, 2nd ed pg 259

Comment: Please see my answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431248/is-there-any-example-of-spontaneous-symmetry-breaking-in-simple-mechanical-syste